# I want to execute a terminal command using php?

Tags: 12.04, system, phpmyadmin

I have tried `exec`, `shell_exec`, `system`, but they didn't work for me. The command I want to execute is as follows:

```
./toolkits/collaborative_filtering/svdpp --training=/home/zubair/graphchi_v0.2.6/graphchi/smallnetflix_mm.train.txt --validation=/home/zubair/graphchi_v0.2.6/graphchi/smallnetflix_mm.validate.txt --binary_relevance_thresh=4 --sgd_gamma=1e-6 --max_iter=30 --quiet=1 --sgd_step_dec=0.9999 --sgd_lambda=1e-6 --D=3 --minival=1 --maxval=10`
```

Answer (score 2):

Since php is not a compiled language, you can't execute it directly.  You must tell the system how to open it, just like a shell script.

With a shell script, you can run it using `sh filename`, or `bash filename`.    Another way is to write the script with a special comment line at the top, called a "sha-bang", or "crash-bang"; for a bash script, it's like this:
`#!/bin/bash`
You can then make the file executable, and execute it like a normal program.

You can do the same for php.  Either run it under php, if you have it (`php xxx.php`), or add the sha-bang, but make it say `/bin/php` rather than `/bin/bash`